# LVM Reduce a RAID6 array

Tags: lvm, software-raid

I made the mistake of setting up RAID6 using LVM directly. For better flexibility, I need to switch to managing RAID through MDRAID.

Is there a way I can reduce the size of the array (freeing up disks). Alternatively, can I remove a disk from the array putting the array in a degraded state?

I would then create an array in MDRAID, migrate data, and then migrate the rest of the disks.

This is an Ubuntu 14.04 VM.

Comment: RAID6 using what? What is it currently?

Comment: It was made with a 'lvcreate --type raid6 ...' command. My understanding is that when you use LVM for raid, it is actually the MDRAID underneath, but all of the command functionality is through the LVM interface. The LVM interface seems to have limits on what you can do.

Comment: Well, if it is a LVM, you can do what you can do with a LVM, so copy it some place safe, recreate the RAID the way you want, and copy it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up following this procedure:

- Unmount the Logical Volume
- "Deactivate" the Logical Volume
- Use `pvremove --force --force` on one physical volume. The --force --force is required to remove an in-use physical volume
- Re-"Activate" the Logical Volume with a `--partial` flag
- Re-mount the Logical Volume

The end result is that I can read all of the data on my array. Since I started with RAID6, I even still have redundancy of one device. I also have one disk free and can use that to start building an array in MD.

Answer (score 0):

As recent LVM version use MDRAID for provide RAID personalities, it **should** be possible to resize the array. You had to

1. reduce the LVM volumes with `lvresize`
2. reduce the LVM physical volume with `pvresize`
3. if the array is not automatically resized, use `mdadm` to do it. You can find the array detail with `cat /proc/mdstat`

However, consider that RAID6 reshape needs quite a bit of time. *Maybe is faster/easier to backup all your data and destroy/recreate the array.*

Comment: `cat /proc/mdstat` says nothing about the raid array. I used LVM to set it up. The only reason I think it uses MD under the hood is the discussion at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150644/raiding-with-lvm-vs-mdraid-pros-and-cons.

Comment: I can confirm that recent LVM versions use MDRAID to manage RAID personalities. However, previous LVM versions implemented devicemapper-based RAID 0/1/5/6 personalities. Maybe your LVM installation use the latter method.

Comment: I have no idea. Based on the link in my previous comment, I assumed that it was MD under the hood. However, `cat /proc/mdstat` only shows the new array I created myself (see my answer on what I actually did). It doesn't show anything related to the LVM array. My LVM version is 2.02.98(2) (2012-10-15)